# How to save data in DB when change field on foreign key? Django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.UUIDField()

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now my db contains the data of `brand_id`  for each `Car` object, if i change it from `UUIDField` to `ForeignKey`, the data will lost.

How can i save the data using one migration?

Comment: What is the `id` of the `Brand`, a `UUIDField`?

Answer (score 1):

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

in the database migration file

from django.db import migrations

def update_something_foreign_key(apps, schema_editor):
Model = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'Model')
Something = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'Something')

```
for model in Model.objects.all():
    something_id = model.something_id
    something = Something.objects.filter(id=something_id).first()
    if something:
        model.something = something
        model.save()
```

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('your_app_name', 'previous_migration_name'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(update_something_foreign_key),
]
```

Comment: but please, edit your answer